# Microsoft Graph List activityStatistics

Tags: http, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, office365api, microsoft-live-meeting

I follow the web page(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/activitystatistics-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)
and use MS Graph Explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview) as [the image show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfDEY.jpg)
to List activityStatistics ,but always get the following information .

```
{
"error": {
"code": "UnknownError",
"message": "{"Code":"Forbidden","Message":"Access to the requested resource is forbidden.","Target":"ReadUserAnalyticsV2","Details":[{"Code":"PolicyNotSatisfied","Message":"The following authorization requirements are not satisfied: UserRequireAdvancedMyALicense."}]}",
"innerError": {
"request-id": "0bf68858-17f4-498c-bb2b-c2c185e51e78",
"date": "2020-04-08T18:22:22"
}
}
}
```

And I have try license use get https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/analytics/settings
to check that I have the license [like the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDjuI.png)

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('5eed83b1-2949-4c9f-b42a-ee9055dfb4fd')/analytics/settings",
    "hasLicense": true,
    "hasOptedOut": false,
    "hasGraphMailbox": true
}
```

How can I solve the problem ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post your code so we can look at it

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my post with the execute picture.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/social-overview?view=graph-rest-beta#help-users-gain-insights-into-their-work-patterns), for the analytics API to return results for a user, the current user analytics settings must show a valid MyAnalytics license, be opted in to using MyAnalytics, and have a cloud-hosted mailbox that’s graph-enabled.

The signed user (/me) should have the following response for GET /me/analytics/settings
{
  "hasGraphMailbox": true,
  "hasLicense": true,
  "hasOptedOut": false
}

Then Analytics API will return results.
If the user doesn't have license, you can assign license via [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/workplace-analytics/use/assigning-licenses-with-powershell)

The user should also have "Microsoft MyAnalytics(Full)" license assigned as shown in the below picture. To assign a license, you can navigate to portal.office.com.
[image]

Comment: I have check GET /me/analytics/settings  ,  that I have the license , list bellow


{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('5eed83b1-2949-4c9f-b42a-ee9055dfb4fd')/analytics/settings",
    "hasLicense": true,
    "hasOptedOut": false,
    "hasGraphMailbox": true
}

Comment: Can you sign in into https://myanalytics.microsoft.com/ and confirm whether you can see the activity data for the user?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the additional license requirements(Microsoft MyAnalytics(Full)). Once you assign the license, it will take a few minutes to reflect the changes. I have attached a screen shot for your reference.